# initialization order of thread_local vs. global variables

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

C.h:

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
public:
  explicit C(int id) { std::cout<<"Initialized "<<id<<"\n"; }
};
```

1.cpp:

```
#include "C.h"

C global(1);
```

2.cpp:

```
#include "C.h"

thread_local C thread(2);

int main() {}
```

My question is: Is it guaranteed that `global` will be initialized before `thread`?

The C++ standard is somewhat vague on this point, as far as I understand it. It says (from the C++17 [n4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) draft):

> **[basic.start.static]  Static initialization**
>
> Variables with static storage duration are initialized as a
>   consequence of program initiation. Variables with thread storage
>   duration are initialized as a consequence of thread execution.

It stands to reason that "program initiation" happen before "thread execution", but since both those expressions appear in the standard only in that place, I'm seeking advise from actual language lawyers.

Comment: IIRC there are guarantees by the standart. But all vendors initialize `thread_local` variables upon first use.

Comment: "_It stands to reason that "program initiation" happen before "thread execution"_" I guess it depends on whether what does "_program initiation_" (and goes on to execute `main()`) is itself a thread or not (in C++ terminology). If it _is_, then one might expect things done _as a consequence of thread execution_ to happen _before_ things done _as a consequence of program initiation_.

Comment: Also related: active [CWG issue 2148](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2148).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to use the C++20 working draft since the wording there is a little cleaner, although none of the real rules have changed.

First, `thread_local` behaves basically like `static` as far as non-local goes: [[basic.stc.thread]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#stc.thread-2):

> [ Note: A variable with thread storage duration is initialized as specified in [basic.start.static], [basic.start.dynamic], and [stmt.dcl] and, if constructed, is destroyed on thread exit ([basic.start.term]). — end note ]

Yes, it's a note. But a non-local object declared `thread_local` is basically `static` so this makes sense.

Now, neither `global` nor `thread` have constant initialization - so both are zero initialized and then they have to undergo dynamic initialization. To [[basic.start.dynamic]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic)!

> Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is unordered if the variable is an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, is partially-ordered if the variable is an inline variable that is not an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is ordered.

Neither of our variables are specializations, neither of them are inline. So both are *ordered*.

> A declaration D is *appearance-ordered* before a declaration E if
>
> - D appears in the same translation unit as E, or
> - the translation unit containing E has an interface dependency on the translation unit containing D,
>
> in either case prior to E.

Our declarations are not appearance-ordered with respect to each other.

> Dynamic initialization of non-local variables V and W with static storage duration are ordered as follows:

Alright, sub-bullet 1:

> If V and W have ordered initialization and the definition of V is appearance-ordered before the definition of W, or if V has partially-ordered initialization, W does not have unordered initialization, and for every definition E of W there exists a definition D of V such that D is appearance-ordered before E,

Doesn't apply. It's a complicated condition, but it doesn't apply.

> Otherwise, if the program starts a thread other than the main thread before either V or W is initialized, it is unspecified in which threads the initializations of V and W occur; the initializations are unsequenced if they occur in the same thread.

Nope, no threads.

> Otherwise, the initializations of V and W are indeterminately sequenced.

There we go. `global` and `thread` are indeterminately sequenced.

---

Note also that:

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred.

and:

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with thread storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of the initial function of a thread or is deferred.

Comment: Can you expand on what "interface dependency" means? I failed to find the definition in the standards I found.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh You can look up terms in the [index](http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex), which can then point you to the [definition](http://eel.is/c++draft/module.import#def:interface_dependency).

Comment: Thank you. It is as I suspected: this is a C++20 only thing. A pity, as it would have been useful for me in what I'm trying to do. I ended up forcing the order by putting in a simple pointer and manually allocating it the first time I need it :-(

Comment: @ShacharShemesh Well it only makes sense in the context of modules, so naturally :-)

Comment: The use case (in C++17) is a base class that needs a global supporting it, and derived templates that are expected to be set for globals as well. There is inherent dependency, but not one C++ recognizes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee and there cannot be any form of guarantee of it - at least currently.

Imagine following case, you have another unrelated `static` global variable `Z` that uses your `thread_local` variable during initialization or, say, even creates another thread and uses it - all during its initialization.

Now it just happens that this `static` global variable `Z` gets initialized prior to your static global variable `global`. This implies that the `thread_local` variable had to be initialized prior to your static global variable.

Note: currently, there is no way to guarantee in which order static global variables are being initialized - a known issue of C++. So if you use one global variable inside another it might or might not lead to an error - technically a UB. Don't think that it affects `thread_local` variables in any way as their initialization mechanism tends to be very different.

Comment: That does not immediately follow. It might well be that the case you describe is UB.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh I don't remember of any rules forbidding usage of `thread_local` variables inside initialization of `static` variables.

Comment: I don't think it's any different than relying on another global that is initialized in a different translation unit.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh it is because `thread_local` are initialized via a very different mechanism from `static` variables. Most compilers simply initialize them upon first use. While the `static` initialized from `static` is just a general mess.

Comment: That was not the question, however. The standard does not promise me that `thread_local` are initialized on first use, or I wouldn't have this problem. I'm asking about avoiding UB, not making things work in practice.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh you got your UB or not UBZ. `thread_local` variables can be used inside static variable initialization - nothing forbids that. Thus they can be initialized prior to static variables. Your question falls back to the same fiasco of global static variable initialization order.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh I think you ask the wrong question here. Instead of which is initialized first - you should've asked "is it fine to use `thread_local/static` in other `thread_local/static` variables?" Generally, the answer was supposed to be "yes, `thread_local/static` variables are meant to be initialized before first use. So unless you have circular dependency in initialization, everything is fine." Unfortunately, it is not exactly the case due to aforementioned fiasco - and I highly doubt it was intentional fail. I don't think there were other reports regarding such problem.

Comment: I don't get this answer. Only the very last sentence seems to relate to this question, and it misses a fundamental philosophy of the ISO Standard. The Standard isn't concerned about initialization mechanisms, that's up to the implementors. The Standard describes only observable behavior, not how that behavior should be realized.

Comment: @MSalters You should reread the answer. It describes a valid situation "observable behaviour" in which one has to initialize `thread_local` variable before a static variable. Thus standart cannot guarantee something like "all static variables are intialized before `thread_local`".

Comment: @ALX23z: Even if we assume that logic is correct, that merely tells us that one particular order is impossible. But as you introduced another variable `Z`, there are now 3! = 6 possible orders, so there are 5 other possible orders that you didn't touch upon. This doesn't appear to be an improvement, because the original question only had 2 possible orders. Also, the Standard could very well say that all static global variables are initialized before `thread_local` variables; it would make it explicitly undefined to use that uninitialized `thread_local` variable as you described it.

Comment: @ALX23z: The question is tagged [language-lawyer]. It's explicitly asking for "authoritative sources" , and the [c++17] tag says that the authoritative source has to be the C++17 standard. Your answer is not based on any standard or source whatsoever; it borders on an opinion.

Comment: @MSalters "The question is tagged [language-lawyer]. It's explicitly asking for "authoritative sources"". No that doesn't imply that - it is your own interpretation of the tag. He asks for theoretical C++ rules - I provide answer on what can or cannot be in the rules and why.

Comment: @MSalters: Another aspect of the ISO philosophy is that there's no need to have the Standard require that implementations intended for various tasks uphold behavioral guarantees that would benefit those tasks.  If 99% of implementations would process something in the same useful fashion, the only time anyone should care about whether the Standard requires that would be if some implementation's customers would benefit from having it do something else.  Since compiler writers should know more about their customers' needs than the Committee ever could, there's no need for Committee involvement.